# I can't update an object inside an array with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I want to modify one of the objects in the array, I have printed what the deck.save () returns and it is indeed the updated deck but when I check the database, the data was not updated.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong

```
const { deckId, cardId } = req.body;

const deck = await DeckModel.findById(deckId);

const index = deck.cards.findIndex((card) => card.id == cardId);
 
deck.cards[index].level++;

await deck.save();
```

my deckModel schema:

```
new Schema({
  name: String,
  owner: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
  cards: Array,
});
```

Also, when I try to put something like deck.cards.push(newCard) or pop (), the database updates perfectly.